# Unity - make character walk towards touch/drag position? In 3D space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-development

Ok, I have a 3D Unity game built for iOS where these controls will be implemented (in a first person shooter manner):

1. Camera follows just behind character
2. Keeping finger on screen makes character walk, finger up makes it stop
3. THIS is the problem: wherever the user has started touching the screen, whatever direction they drag (forward, backwards, left right) the character will walk indefinitely in that direction.

This must have done already but I cant find anything anywhere. I have the camera as a child of the character, so that's taken care of but for char movement all I have is:

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

            Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, -10f));
            transform.Translate(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime) - transform.position);

        }
```

Which doesn't work as needed. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try to use any king of UI joysticks (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631) for example

And access its parameters something like this:

```
public class TestMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    public FloatingJoystick Joystick; //Set in the inspector, prefab from the asset
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(Joystick.Horizontal, Joystick.Vertical) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```